# Creating directory shortcuts with WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-shortcut

I'm trying to create a shortcut to a directory using `ln` in WSL, so that double-clicking it opens the directory: while it works if the shortcut is created in the same disk, it creates a 0 B file if the disks are different; for example:

`ln -rs /mnt/d/test /mnt/d/test-1`: works.

`ln -rs /mnt/c/test /mnt/d/test-1`: doesn't work, it creates the 0 B file.

Without `-r`, it does't work even on the same disk: `ln -s /mnt/d/sym/test /mnt/d/sym/test-1` creates a 0 B file (but `ln -s test test-s`, without paths, while being in `/mnt/d/sym`, works).

[image: Example]

Icon test-1 is the working shortcut: I can open it and it opens test.

Icon test-2 is what I was referring to as "0 B file": it isn't shown as a directory shortcut, and I can't open it like I can test-1.

How can a directory shortcut be created between different disks?

Comment: Try w/o `-r`. In your case you do not need to be relative

Comment: I tried that too, but without the `-r` it doesn't work even on the same disk; I'll edit the question to add this info, thanks.

Comment: Mauro, this is how soft link work. It create link, not new file with size of 0 bytes.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I added an image hoping to clarify the issue.